# Matrix representations of scalar transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be the scalar transformation on $\mathbb{R}^n$,$n \in \mathbb{N}$, defined by
$$ F(\vec{x}) = k\vec{x},\text{      }k \in \mathbb{R}.  $$

1. Prove that all matrix representations of $F$, relative to any basis of $\mathbb{R^n}$, are identical and find this representation.
2. Under what conditions will $F$ have a well-defined inverse?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like, working through an example? Say, $n=2$, $k=17$?

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers that have been posted?

Comment: Both answers make sense. Thanks so much.

Comment: If you have found the answers helpful, it would be appreciated if you would "accept" one of them by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry I am new here. Just did what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take the standard basis $e_1=(1,0,\cdots, 0)^T, e_2 = (0,1,0,\cdots, 0), \cdots$ the matrix reprsentaion is $kI$ where $I$ is the identity matrix made up of the columns $e_1 e_2, \cdots$

in any other basis the representation of $F$ is $P^{-1}kI P = kI$

Answer (score 2):

1. It is easy to see that the matrix representation will be $kI$, where $I$ is the $n$ x $n$ identity matrix.
2. It will always have an inverse except for case where $k=0$ because then determinant of the matrix $kI$ will be $0$ and it would have no inverse.